# convert timestamp to date/hour/minute from database to datatable php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have timestamp saved in mysql database and i want it to be converted to date and hours and minutes and be displayed in a datatable like that (1375628707) want it -> 12/8/2013 (21:36:10)

```
<?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$row['ext']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['user_id']?></td>
                        <td><a title="<?=$row['image_description']?>"> <?=$row['image_name']?> </a> </td>
                        <td><?=$row['upload_time']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['image_id']?></td>
                        <td><a id="download" href="<?=$row['download_link']?>"><img src="download.png"></a></td>

                    <?php
                }
                ?>
```

i don't know what to add to the line

```
<td><?=$row['upload_time']?></td>
```

to be converted to real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use PHP standard  [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
<td><?= date('d/m/Y (H:i:s)', $row['upload_time']) ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is to do it in the query

```
.. DATE_FORMAT(upload_time,'%D %M %Y at %l:%i%p')as upload_time ...
```